# Unable to run build on iPhone after updating to iOS11 with Xcode 9 GMSeed, Error Message: "dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios11, xcode9

So after spending hours sweeping the web for answers, the recommended solution to this problem was to go to XCode.app/contents/developer/platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and then delete the directory that matches your device's iOS. Which I did and I got the following results:

BEFORE DELETING THE DIRECTORY "iOS11(15A372)"

> Error Message: dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

AFTER DELETING THE DIRECTORY iOS "11(15A372)"

> Error Message: This iPhone 6s is running iOS 11.0 (15A372), which may not be
>   supported by this version of Xcode.

Help!

Answer (score 5):

please follow the following step.

step 1- Download file that you need below:

[iOS 11 beta](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByKO5dRSZg8MSjVDRkVWUUQybWc/view)

step 2- Copy this iOS 10.2 image file to: **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/**

Restart Xcode.
Now it Working fine.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error(dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed). I have iOS11 on my phone, not iOS11 beta